# Why is IIS7 ASP.Net MVC4 transmitting images very slowly?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4

I have started developing in C# MVC4 after 8 years of PHP and plenty of VB and C#.

My current problem is this: the application serves the images very slowly, yet only some of them. 32x32px images are served instantly, as they should, yet a 439KB PNG image is downloaded in over 30s. It's not a bandwidth problem, I checked on Remote Desktop Connection to the VPS that serves the files and it was slow to load there too.

Also jquery.min (181.5KB bundle) is 12.14s (measured by firebug).

I have tested with both static and dynamic compression ON / OFF, no improvement.
I have also tested with

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"></modules>
```

on and off, still no improvement. I've had this problem both on Windows 2008 SP1 and on Azure.

Problem appears on IE9, FF, Chrome and Opera.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code of how you are rendering images? Where are you storing those images?  Also, with MVC4 do you sprite generation on?

Comment: `<img src="/Content/themes/base/images/flags/32/en.png" width="32px" height="32px" alt="English" />` works perfectly

Comment: `<img src="/Content/themes/base/temp/slider1.png" />`, 439KB PNG file, takes >30s to download.

Comment: all of this is straight HTML, controller+model code is <100 lines, no database, files are stored on the hard drive, in C:\inetpub\...

Comment: do you have a public url where we can view the performance?

Comment: [link](http://www.edello.com), the large image that replaces the green div.

Comment: In Chrome, slider1.png downloaded in 640ms for me.  Your jQuery bundle (with a cache buster) took 5 sec though

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support, the problem was caused by the ISP, and thanksfully their support fixed it.

Comment: What was the issue with the ISP? We are having a similar issue with ours